# vue-cli-service build --target lib loses images path when imported as lib

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I followed this [guide](https://medium.com/justfrontendthings/how-to-create-and-publish-your-own-vuejs-component-library-on-npm-using-vue-cli-28e60943eed3) to create my npm module. My [repo](https://github.com/dnhyde/vue-simplest-hue-radial-picker) contains in the src/assets folder an svg image (hue-cirle.svg).

When building with `vue-cli-service build --target lib --name <lib-name>` the svg image is bundled under `dist/img/hue-circle123456.svg`.

Now when installing the module with `npm install --save <module>` the path remains `src/img/hue-circle123456.svg`, while it should refer to the svg image from the node_modules dist folder and not to a non-existing `hue-circle123456.svg` image from the main Vue App src folder.

Basically what happens is that the svg image path is wrong in the Vue project that uses my module. I tried to add the `~` to force webpack to interpret it as a module dependency as suggested [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/193) but it did not work.

In the end I gave up and embedded the svg in the html template as you can see in the [repo](https://github.com/dnhyde/vue-simplest-hue-radial-picker/blob/master/src/components/HueCircleSvg.vue). Nonetheless, I ask this question since I could not find any solution and I, as well as others, may need to solve this in order to use image resources in custom modules built with `vue-cli-service build --target lib --name <lib-name>` command.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm surprised no one has answered this yet :/

Comment: I don't think `alias` will fix this.
When I check the bundle file after build as lib. I found my image was `webpack.__require__` and the path is `localhost:8080/xxx/my-image`
But when I use the lib as a dependency in my `project1`, I saw the image request but there is no real image data responded with a success code 200

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a similar problem, my fix for the time being is to add the following to `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    extract: false
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule("images")
      .use("url-loader")
      .loader("url-loader")
      .tap(options => Object.assign(options, { limit: Infinity }));
  }
};
```

This inlines all assets as base64 [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).

Taken from: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports

**Edit:**

For SVG try this:

```js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    extract: false
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg')
    svgRule.uses.clear()

    svgRule
      .test(/\.svg$/)
      .use('svg-url-loader') // npm install --save-dev svg-url-loader
      .loader('svg-url-loader')
  }
};
```

Remember this is far from optimal and a workaround!

Comment: You are my life savior.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for resolve path with WebPack :

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

The path for assets can be resolve like this for example :

```
process.env.NODE_ENV == "production ? path.resolve(process.cwd(), "dist/assets") : path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets");
```

Production :

```
process.cwd() // Where the application is running. You can pack it for example.
```